# Passing a jade value to Ember.js through Handlerbars

Tags: node.js, ember.js, pug, handlebars.js

I have a Node.js project that is using Jade for the html templating, and on the client side I am using Ember.js with Handlebars.  I have a value that I pass into my Jade template from my routes file

home.js

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {       
    res.render('index', { title: 'Home Page.  ', flickrApiKey: nconf.get('flickr:apiKey') })
});
```

and then inside of the jade file

index.jade

```
{{#view Piccee.FlickrHeaderView api_key=!{flickrApiKey}}}
```

The line in index.jade does not work however, but if I change it to

```
{{#view Piccee.FlickrHeaderView api_key=123}}
```

it does work.  So, I just need to figure out how to pass a Jade variable into a Handlebars call.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are attempting but this works:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
   <p>Your first name is #{firstName}</p>
   <!-- and then inside a view -->
   {{#view}}
       <span>#{firstName}</span>
   {{/view}}
</script>
```

Accessing template variables inside .jade files works by prefixing **#** sign

Hope this helps!